# Can't run Apple Hardware Test as Mac crashes

Tags: mac, snow-leopard, hardware, apple-hardware-test

My Macbook: Apple MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.0 13" (White/07).

Main problem: Mac goes black screen and shuts down when I try and load the Apple HW Test by holding down D as the computer turns on. It goes to a black screen with a flashing underscore like it's about to do something but then just shuts down. I am using the DVD as per apple's instructions.

Why I wanna do this: I'm trying to put some new life into my old mac and want to know if it's worth my while and where I should be spending money. The mac makes funny noises when it boots ([listen here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dgSnz1XnP0NnNTVElsUjY0eDhOaDFmRmhyRWQyUHZMamNV/edit?usp=sharing)) and when it's running ([listen here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_dgSnz1XnP0bndSS0tXYmNHcXY4SldveDF2ZmZ0Mi1TYk5F/edit?usp=sharing)). I imagine there could be a problem with the HD, maybe the fans, (definitely the battery, is has 0% capacity), but yes want to know before I start spending money.

Desired solution: How to get Apple HW test to work, or suggestions for a better alternative.

Comment: The first sound is the optical drive ejecting without anything to eject. This isn't special and I'm convinced it always did this. The second one sounds just like an old fan plus a correctly operating hdd...

Comment: Yeah starts up fine if not trying to run HW test

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct AHT DVD for that machine?  I think I've seen similar behaviour when using the wrong version...

Comment: Hmm I'll admit I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Try ejecting the DVD, and instead hold alt-d at startup.  On some machines (not sure what the criteria is) I've found that this downloads AHT over the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apple hardware Test are very hardware specific.

To know yours you need to know the exact model for it.

Then you can look up and download in this [database](http://download.info.apple.com/Apple_Hardware_Test/018-[MODEL%20%3E%20NUMBER]-A.dmg):

or from here:

https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest

Yours is probably in this group

MacBook

```
MacBook2,1 Mac-F4208CA9
MacBook2,1 Mac-F4208CAA
MacBook3,1 Mac-F22788C8
MacBook4,1 Mac-F22788A9
MacBook5,1 Mac-F42D89A9
MacBook5,1 Mac-F42D89C8
MacBook5,2 Mac-F22788AA
MacBook6,1 Mac-F22C8AC8
MacBook7,1 Mac-F22C89C8
```

Here are some [instructions](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1509) how to and some [more here](http://rivenbyfive.blogspot.com/2012/01/download-and-run-apple-hardware-test.html).

Comment: I found my model, downloaded the diagnostics file, placed it in library so had hope. However, holding down D or alt-D whilst booting (without the DVD inserted) has no effect and the computer boots as normal :(

Comment: Try holding cmd+d, and tell me where did you install the file ?

Answer (score 1):

#### Hardware defects

It is likely that some of the hardware that is needed for the hardware test to run, is defect. My personal experience is that this will most likely be one of your 2 RAM DIMMS. You can safely eject 1 and try the test again (and the same goes for the other).

If you run your hardware test from CD/DVD, you can also do this for your HD, and other components.

Comment: I'm thinking about removing this 'answer' as it is based on speculation only.

Comment: Well, if you've had personal experience with this issue and this procedure worked, it's worth a shot right?

Comment: True, and I think this indeed might be the issue. I'll keep it here. Let us know how it works out.

Comment: I know this is lazy but.. I've already had a diagnostics check at a genius bar (but they said the AHT is more complete) and it didn't identify any components as having issues (apart from the battery). Could the components still be causing an issue or is this unlikely?

Comment: There are 2 ways the AHT can operate: 1. from it's own ROM memory, so it does not invoke the harddrive. 2. from a special partition on the harddrive. Check http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14291?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US to see if you are 1 or 2. If you are 2, I think it is a corrupted AHT partition. If 1, I still think it's the RAM.